# How do I execute `cargo bench` on a per-file basis?

Tags: rust, benchmarking, rust-cargo

I'm working through [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) problems, and I have each problem in a different file.  As I try different approaches to each problem, I create a series of benchmarks for each problem in its respective file.

My directory structure looks like:

```
euler/
    Cargo.lock
    Cargo.toml
    README.md
    src/
        main.rs
        p001.rs
        p002.rs
        ...etc.
```

The contents of `main.rs` are:

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate primes;
extern crate test;

mod p001;
mod p002;
// ... etc

fn main() {}
```

When I run `cargo bench`, it runs the benchmarks for every single file in my project:

```
$ cargo bench
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.02 secs
     Running target/release/deps/euler_rust-5be87dff38a04da2

running 11 tests
test p001::bench_fold_sum                     ... bench:      12,955 ns/iter (+/- 13,501)
test p001::bench_for_sum                      ... bench:      11,385 ns/iter (+/- 7,383)
test p002::bench_for_sum                      ... bench:         270 ns/iter (+/- 90)
test p002::bench_takewhile_filter_mutable_sum ... bench:         322 ns/iter (+/- 333)
test p002::bench_takewhile_filter_sum         ... bench:         512 ns/iter (+/- 379)
test p002::bench_takewhile_sum                ... bench:         273 ns/iter (+/- 117)
test p002::bench_while_sum                    ... bench:         286 ns/iter (+/- 240)
```

I'm interested in only running the benchmarks contained in one file, but specifying the filename after `cargo bench` yields the following:

```
$ cargo bench src/p002.rs
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.02 secs
     Running target/release/deps/euler_rust-5be87dff38a04da2

running 0 tests

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 11 filtered out
```

How do you run the benchmarks in a single file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no direct "run the tests contained in this file on disk" option. The help for `cargo bench` says:

```
$ cargo bench --help
Execute all benchmarks of a local package

Usage:
    cargo bench [options] [BENCHNAME] [--] [<args>...]

Options:
    BENCHNAME                    If specified, only run benches containing this string in their names
```

Additionally, files correspond to Rust modules, and modules are part of the test name.

You can combine these two things together and use `cargo bench my_file_slash_module_name` to restrict the tests that are run. In your specific case:

```
cargo bench p002
```

If you happen to have other tests or modules that contain this same substring, you can sometimes get away by adding the colons:

```
cargo bench p002::
```

Comment: cargo bench --bench file_name